# Assigning json output to javascript variable in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

JSON.parse or JSON.stringigy is not working while passing the axios response to variable

```
 axios.get('api/v0/graph/instance/'+ this.props.selectedNode )
  .then(response => {
      console.log('Starting of tree node message' + response.data.message);
        //var message = JSON.parse(response.data.message);
      var RtnJSONVal = JSON.parse(response.data.message);

      console.log('value of the message variable is' + RtnJSONVal.length );
      var fields = RtnJSONVal;
```

response.data.message is how in the value as below

```
{  
   "guid":"FCU1",
   "group_parent":"room_687",
   "p":{  

   },
   "ctime":1527225563237,
   "mtime":1527225563239,
   "instanceOf":"FCU",
   "coordinates":{  
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[  
         32.76473,
         35.01616
      ],
      "crs":{  
         "type":"name",
         "properties":{  
            "name":"EPSG:4326"
         }
      }
   },
   "ref-in":[  
      {  
         "src":"FCU1_Extractor",
         "tgt":"FCU1",
         "refType":"hasAsset"
      },
      {  
         "src":"FCU1_Diffuser",
         "tgt":"FCU1",
         "refType":"hasAsset"
      }
   ],
   "ref-out":[  
      {  
         "src":"FCU1",
         "tgt":"room_687",
         "refType":"hasLocation"
      }
   ]
}
```

But when i try to assign to variable i am getting error as

"value of the message variable is[object Object]"

Comment: axios gives you an already parsed response. No need to parse it.

Comment: I still need it to assign it to a variable to traverse through the values and display the output using return part of reactjs. How do i do that..?

Comment: @SatishNarasimha Could you clarify? If you assign to variable with simply: var RtnJSONVal = response.data.message; does that not work?

Comment: I need the entire JSON message to be assigned to simple variable to make it as "ARRAY variable" like var data = {JSON MESSAGE}. If i do that, it is not taking in reactjs

Comment: I am fine if we can read the message using "For loop" and assign it to array. any best approach please. It should be able to read sub elements as well

Comment: Did you solve it ?  If yes, kindly share.  Me too facing the same issue